# Is there any method to create JSON (Array of String) Directly from Select statement in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to run select statement on a Table `[Admin].[User]`. This table has a column `Username`.

I want to get all the Usernames in a single select statement in a single `varchar` variable which may look like this:

`["some@gmail.com", "myself@yahoo.com", "none@outlook.com"]`

Comment: Please add a tag that makes it clear what database (and version) you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you are using Microsoft SQL Server, you should be able to do this using [`SELECT ... FOR JSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-for-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause.

The format of output is however somewhat different, the closest I could get to yours is:

```
[{"username":"some@gmail.com"},{"username":"myself@yahoo.com"},{"username":"none@outlook.com"}]
```

Some more related documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/44805

Comment: SQL Server 2022 has a nice function called JSON_Array would fix the problem. Anything before that would involve string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are are using mysql you can use the function "JSON_ARRAY(column_name)" to get JSON values  Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html for further details. Example/Sample

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY(id, name) FROM division
```

Resulting

```
JSON_ARRAY(id, name)
[1, "West Bengal"]
[2, "24 PARAGANAS SOUTH"]
[3, "Baruipur"]
[4, "BEGAMPUR G.P."]
[5, "HARAL (P)"]
```

However, if you have to get an object then USE JSON_OBJECT('key1', column_name1, ....,'keyn', coulmnn) Where key is a string and the other is the fieldname from a table.

Hope this helps.

With respect to your question, where you want just the Username (and NOT JSON) you can use the GROUP_CONCAT (ref: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) which will just produce a comma-separated (default comma refer to the documentation to change the separator) values.

```
SELECT CONCAT( '["' , GROUP_CONCAT(Username SEPARATOR '", "') , '"]') FROM 
FROM tableName GROUP BY Username
```

Though the user has not specified which database is he seeking solutions for (initially), later, he has added "[]" thus guessing that he is referring to SQLServer, if so, please follow the other answer by @jiri.

Comment: Note that the original question had square brackets around table name and in the desired output - someone else than original author edited them out, I just returned them back. This might impact both desired output and what DB we assume the author uses.

Comment: also read the following question it might help you ref: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)